# Using gem Curb (curl) to download file

Tags: ruby, curb

I have understood that I could use the RubyGem Curb to fulfill my needs of curl'ing down a file to my computer. But I cannot figure out how to actually "touch" the file. This is what I have got so far

```
include 'rubygems'
include 'curb'

curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://wordpress.org/latest.zip')
curl.perform
```

I think I understand that `perform` actually downloads the file. But how can I interact with the file afterwards? Where is it downloaded to?

Regards,
Mattias

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a zip file through Net::HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386159/download-a-zip-file-through-nethttp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file can be accessed with the body_str method.

```
puts curl.body_str
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs at http://rdoc.info/gems/curb/0.7.15/.

After `perform`, the content is in e.g. `curl.body_str`.

Comment: How would I go about to convert this to an actual zip-file I can open in Finder (I am using OSX).

Comment: I have tried `file = File.new("test.zip", "w+")
file.puts $filebody
file.close`

Comment: Should I perhhaps post a new question instead? :)

Comment: Probably best to write an `on_body` handler, something like `curl.on_body {|d| File.open('your.zip', 'a') {|f| f.write d} }`.

Comment: I think `puts` adds an extra newline, that'd break your zipfile.

Comment: It is not working. I posted a new [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383143/zipfile-download-through-curl-to-an-actual-zip-file-in-your-file-structure)