# Zipfile download through CURL to an actual Zip-file in your file structure

Tags: ruby, file, curl, curb

I am trying to build a file downloader with the RubyGem Curb. (Look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382149/using-gem-curb-curl-to-download-file).)

I am trying to download a zip file and then with the class File I am trying to actually make the file so that I can double click it in Finder (I am on OS X). How would I go about to convert this "Curl'ed" body to a zip-file.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'

class Download
  def start
    curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://wordpress.org/latest.zip')
    curl.perform
    curl.on_body {
      |d| f = File.new('test.zip', 'w') {|f| f.write d}
    }
  end
end

dl = Download.new
dl.start
```

I am not getting any error, neither can I find any file. I have tried absolute paths with no difference.

Comment: You're adding the `on_body` event after calling `perform`, which transfers the body. Does the code work if you create that event before calling `curl.perform`?

Comment: Ahh of course I have to call `on_body` before `perform`. I also had to change the File.new parameter `'w'` to `'a'`

Comment: Great, glad that fixed it. I'll add this as an answer as well so other people can find the solution easily :)

Comment: @maetthew, could you check-mark the answer as good?

Comment: @Tim Snowwhite @Hans Engel I was just about to ask you to post it as an answer, good you beat me to it :) Checked it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the `on_body` event after calling `perform`, which transfers the body. If you move the event declaration to before the `perform` call, this should work.

Answer (score 4):

I am using ruby 2.0

and my code is:

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://somepage.cz/index.html')
curl.on_body do |d|
  f = File.open('output_file.html', 'w') {|f| f.write(d)}
end
curl.perform
```

I had to change `File.new` to `File.open` without this it didn't worked.
Moving `curl.perfom` on the end does helped me.